# Need help Creating a coinflip in html/js that will return an image for each flip

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I want to be able to press a button on my webpage that simulates a 50/50 coin toss. I need a heads and tails image to return depending on the outcome.

I started off with this:

```
<script> function coinFlip() { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); } </script>
```

Comment: Not much, I have the images I want to use and an empty webpage.

Comment: There are a couple ways to approach this. But I'd first try to learn some JavaScript and some HTML to create the solution. Try out making it yourself, then when you have some code and you're unable to proceed, ask the question here. Your question is gonna get downvoted because it sounds like you're just asking us to write code for you. TRY to get a solution yourself, then ask questions if you need help. We're here as long as you put in the effort first.

Comment: Fair enough, I started off with this: <script>
 function coinFlip() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a random number which will have a 50/50 probability of being odd or even and thus you can display heads or tails likewise.
First write the image tag,

```
<img src="emptyImg.jpg" id="tossImg">
<button onclick="tossCoin()">Toss</button>
```

Now you can write your toss() function as,

```
function tossCoin(){
//This will generate a number between 1 to 10 randomly
    var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    var myImg = document.getElementById("tossImg");
    if(r%2==0){
        myImg.src = "heads.jpg";
    }else{
        myImg.src = "tails.jpg";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Manipulate the rotate degree to set the outcome as head or tail.

```css
/* flip cards */
.card__flip {
  position: relative;
  width : 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.card__front,
.card__back {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  
}

.card__front,
.card__back {
    background-color: green;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}

.card__back {
    background-color: red;
 transform: rotateX(-540deg);
}

.card__flip.effect__hover:hover .card__front {
 transform: rotateX(-1800deg);
}

.card__flip.effect__hover:hover .card__back {
 transform: rotateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="card__flip effect__hover">
  <div class="card__front"> Head
</div>
  <div class="card__back"> Tail
</div>
</div>
```